# RSA_private_decrypt causes memory leaks on Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, openssl

I can encrypt  and decrypt messages with RSA using openssl 1.0.1h and the with it created public and private RSA-2048-Bit Keys on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio C++ 2012. I tried to check what happens when I use the decrypt function (RSA_private_decrypt) on a (for whatever reason) broken and/or tampered with message and noticed that I get memory leaks. For testing this I tried the following code to decrypt an empty memory buffer:

```
RSA *       rsa = NULL;
BYTE        source[256];
BYTE        destin[256];
int         iret;

memset(source, 0, 256);
memset(destin, 0, 256);

//  function to set the private and public keys (verified to work with valid data)
iret = SetRSAKey(rsa, ENCRYPTION_KEY_SERVER, ENCRYPTION_KEY_CLIENT);

int length = RSA_size(rsa);

iret = RSA_private_decrypt(length, source, destin, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

RSA_free(rsa);

RAND_cleanup ();
EVP_cleanup ();
CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
```

The Visual Leak Detector for Visual Studio reports 4 Memory leaks after exiting:

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 2211 at 0x005037A8: 12 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    18 5F 51 00    00 00 00 00    E0 15 01 00                    ._Q..... ........

---------- Block 2210 at 0x005135A8: 64 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    A8 37 50 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     .7P..... ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........

---------- Block 2209 at 0x005160E8: 96 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    A8 35 51 00    40 BC 30 01    80 BC 30 01    08 00 00 00     .5Q.@.0. ..0.....
    10 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    08 00 00 00    00 02 00 00     ........ ........
    00 01 00 00    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    03 00 00 00    02 00 00 00     ........ ........
    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    02 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    02 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........

---------- Block 2208 at 0x00515F18: 400 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    60 15 00 00    CD CD CD CD    00 00 00 00     ....`... ........
    00 00 00 00    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    79 A0 07 04     ........ ....y...
    72 50 06 04    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     rP...... ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    CD CD CD CD    D0 FB 3E 01     ........ ......>.
    FC A5 3D 01    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ..=..... ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    B5 00 00 00     ........ ........
    68 02 00 00    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     h....... ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    02 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........

Visual Leak Detector detected 4 memory leaks.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
```

If I use a working message instead (encrypted with RSA_public_encrypt) of the empty buffer then there are no memory leaks and the message is being decrypted as expected. But how can I get rid of the memory leaks within openssl when the message is somehow damaged?

Is there maybe a function to test the integrity of the message before I try to decrypt it or do I have to create a CRC and check this myself?

Comment: `ENGINE_cleanup()`, `CONF_modules_unload(1)`, `EVP_cleanup()`, `CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data()`, `ERR_remove_state(0)`, `ERR_free_strings()`. You actually need to call `ERR_remove_state` for each thread in your program. There are some leaks you can't get rid of because the OpenSSL devs don't deem it a problem. Nevermind the accumulating memory leakage from loads and unloads in languages like Java via JNI and C# via P/Invoke.

Comment: Thanks for the information. "ERR_remove_state(0)", or to be more precise "ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);" since "ERR_remove_state" is deprecated, seems to have done it. If you could please post your comment into an answer then I would accept it.

Comment: Also see [How to properly uninitialize OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29845527).

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into the same memory leak problem just using OpenSSL RSA_verify(). The leak actually only occurs when the verification fails. ERR_remove_state(0) seems to fix this problem (credits to the above comment from @jww).

```
  ---------- Block 12440 at 0x00000000CD235350: 536 bytes ----------
      Leak Hash: 0x3AD573C8, Count: 1, Total 536 bytes
      Call Stack (TID 13324):
        0x00000000F8841E70 (File and line number not available): MSVCR120D.dll!malloc
        d:\projects\xy_dev\engine\ext\openssl\openssl-1.0.1j\crypto\mem.c (79): ***.exe!default_malloc_ex + 0x27 bytes
        d:\projects\xy_dev\engine\ext\openssl\openssl-1.0.1j\crypto\mem.c (308): ***.exe!CRYPTO_malloc + 0x18 bytes
        d:\projects\xy_dev\engine\ext\openssl\openssl-1.0.1j\crypto\err\err.c (1019): ***.exe!ERR_get_state + 0x17 bytes
        d:\projects\xy_dev\engine\ext\openssl\openssl-1.0.1j\crypto\err\err.c (730): ***.exe!ERR_put_error + 0x5 bytes
        d:\projects\xy_dev\engine\ext\openssl\openssl-1.0.1j\crypto\rsa\rsa_sign.c (312): ***.exe!int_rsa_verify
        d:\projects\xy_dev\engine\ext\openssl\openssl-1.0.1j\crypto\rsa\rsa_sign.c (337): ***.exe!RSA_verify
```